# Customize Email in Outlook using Add-In-Express

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, customization, outlook-addin

I would like to customize an email message in Outlook (using Add-In-Express). I want to add a check box (with some text) under the Subject (in the pane where the Subject, To, CC etc exists).

anyone can guide how can I do this?

Thanks
Hagai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outloook extensibility model doesn't provide anyhting for that. But you may use [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php). The `TopSubpane` layout allows to place your form right under the ribbon where you can place any .net controls.

[image: TopSubpane]